# IRC client that would preserve the history?

Tags: macos, irc

I use MacOS and **Colloquy**.

I'm not 100% happy for several reasons:

- on laptop every time when device goes to sleep it disconnects me
- I don't see history of the channel when I reconnect

I would like to keep the persistent history of IRC channel. So when I reconnect the messages are waiting for me.

---

There is a very related question here: https://superuser.com/questions/157895/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-persistent-irc-account-that-i-can-read-missed-old-mes

> What you are looking for is a BNC also known as a Bouncer. It sits in
>   the channel at all times from a shell account (as discussed in another
>   answer) and you connect to it. You can have it log and feed you the
>   log when you login or you can read the log on the server itself.

**I wonder if there is software that would serve my needs?**

*(my feeling is that I would need to set up some server in the cloud to cater for that, please prove me wrong)*

I found that link - https://coderwall.com/p/t1c7-w - describing something I would like to do:

> Maintaining chat history is not something that most IRC clients deal with well. Also, I don't really want to leave the terminal (like ever). Luckily, we can use IRSSI and TMUX together to provide a solution.

Before I start paying for a VPS I would like to explore if there are any out-of-the-box solutions.

**Many thanks for suggestions!**

Comment: I know hexchat allows you to save channel logs to local files and then print the last few when you open the client again, but if you can't keep it connected while your laptop sleeps, you'll probably need a bouncer and a computer that stays on (VPS works great for that purpose).

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried just yet but seems plausible: https://www.irccloud.com/

> Stay connected permanently while inactive

as of 7 Dec 2015, staying permanently connected while inactive cost $5/mo.
the free version only lets you stay connected for 2 hours.