# Looking for a IRC bouncer / client combo

Tags: open-source, irc

I am looking for an IRC bouncer that can monitor multiple groups and then a compatible chat client for it.

The bouncer will run on a Linux (RHEL 6) server 24x7 for monitoring, but I would like to be able to fully control it via a Windows (7 x64) machine that will turn on/off after the initial setup.

I hope to find a FLOSS solution to this.

I have looked at [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/157895/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-persistent-irc-account-that-i-can-read-missed-old-mes) already, but the solution there no longer works (link rot) plus I imagine that in the 4 years since then there are better / other options.

Also somewhat unrelated is [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/irc-client-that-would-preserve-the-history), as I already have an available 24x7 server - that question seems to be asking if there is any way around that limitation or via a non-standard IRC network, and is asking for a Mac OS solution (I am looking for a Windows one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

znc is probably what I'd suggest

- has a [webui](http://wiki.znc.in/Webadmin) for config
- [can be controlled over irc](http://wiki.znc.in/Using_commands)
- has the option of [logging](http://wiki.znc.in/Log), and sending you a user defined lines of buffer when you connect

I use it with hexchat (go 32 bit, the 64 bit has a slightly annoying tendancy to crash when disconnected) , but any irc client that's ok with you connecting multiple times to the same server will work